# how to give desktop notification for my php web app?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, triggers

I was create one small application in PHP, for admin and client communication purpose. 
Now I need to show desktop notification while the admin send any message to client.if any updates happen in the database, it should show desktop notification.

1) I want immediate desktop notification like facebook. how could the UI comes to know the modification is done on database.?

2) When the insert or update happens in the database for particular users, and 
the particular user only have to receive the notification. How to do this.?

Any one please give some suggestion to make desktop notification as per I want

Thank you

Comment: Some detail here, along with code samples - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

Answer (score 0):

Use rich desktop notifications to notify users that something important has happened. Notifications appear outside the browser window.

```
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications
```